# Play Animation in AnimationTree from beginning

Tags: godot, godot4

I am attempting to find a way to interrupt a single animation in an AnimationTree and play it from the beginning.

I have a block animation which plays when you get hit, but when hit multiple times, its supposed to play the beginning for each hit. However, it will only play the animation once its finished playing. For the record, I am using the travel function to play the animation, and the attached image is of a snippet of the animation tree (note that I have removed animations leading from idle to another animation becuase of previous issues with travel playing animations I did not want played)

[AnimationTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLo9t.png)